# Can we help support faculty suddenly thrust into online learning?

Tags: discussion

I don't know how much help I can be, but I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105448/online-learning-chat) where people who suddenly find themselves in a situation where they have to entirely change their teaching toolset in the next few weeks can post resources, or at the very least, collectively whine.

I suppose this meta-thread can also serve as an exchange of sorts, if no one objects.

Comment: Nice initiative, thanks!

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano -- my worry is that at the universities where faculty find themselves in this situation, on site support mechanisms will be absolutely swamped, and giving these people a place to try to get some help is a good idea.

Comment: My institution has just decided to move instruction offline for all students after next week's spring break, likely due to fears of students returning from various vacations despite the fact that cases in our local region are low right now. I suspect many others will be making the same considerations. Seems like this is a good initiative, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This is a good idea.  I was also wondering about this in regards to software shopping questions.  We've had at least three recently:

[Creating a secure test environment for a lab practical](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/145321/creating-a-secure-test-environment-for-a-lab-practical)

[Alternatives to big-name proprietary remote-lecturing tools](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/145280/alternatives-to-big-name-proprietary-remote-lecturing-tools)

[Software to live-stream presentations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/145222/software-to-live-stream-presentations)

Two of which are closed, and one which I expect will be.  But at the same time, this seems like a reasonable site to come to in order to find this sort of information.  Should we direct these sorts of questions to the chat?

Comment: Those would be very welcome in the chat, but I wouldn't close the questions either, if they're good questions. The level of support people need might not fit perfectly into the Q\A model, which was my real motivation for starting the room.  Ideally, what we would do is open an online teaching SE, and be lax on enforcing rules.

Comment: Maybe a community wiki in meta or the main site would be a good idea.  I'm a little out of my league here.

Comment: It might be worth opening this as a separate Meta question, and clarifying what the limits to "shopping" should be in these cases. The shopping close reason doesn't get too specific on this, and it seems like https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4062/what-to-do-with-questions-asking-to-evaluate-commercial-online-services is the main guide instead, which seems more narrow than the types of questions that are being closed.

Comment: @BryanKrause That was actually what I originally intended to do, but then I saw this question and added it here.  I went ahead and followed your suggestion too.

Comment: [Here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4675/what-are-the-limits-of-shopping-questions) is the separate meta post about what to do with the links in question (and related ones)

Answer (score 2):

I created [a Meta post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4680/7734) to welcome and guide people visiting our site for this particular reason, collecting relevant questions and giving instructions for new questions. Please contribute, in particular by collecting relevant questions.

Answer (score 0):

A few other groups are also busy in this field and open to participation:

- [EFF](https://www.eff.org/issues/covid-19)
- [FSFE](https://wiki.fsfe.org/action/edit/Activities/FreeSoftware4RemoteWorking)
- [FSF](https://libreplanet.org/wiki/Remote_Communication)
- [IFLA](https://www.ifla.org/covid-19-and-libraries)
- [NOYB](https://noyb.eu/en/interrupted-transmission)
- [SFC](https://sfconservancy.org/blog/2020/mar/17/remotetools/)

In other languages:

- [Chapril](https://www.chapril.org/-services-.html)
- [Continuité Pédagogique](https://www.continuitepedagogique.org/)
- [Framasoft](https://framablog.org/2020/04/04/pour-un-plan-national-pour-la-culture-ouverte-leducation-ouverte-et-la-sante-ouverte/)
- [iorestoacasa.work](https://iorestoacasa.work/)
- [Italian Wikibooks](https://it.wikibooks.org/wiki/Software_libero_a_scuola/Solidariet%C3%A0_digitale)