# I need help adapting my academic workflow to the COVID-19/coronavirus crisis – where do I start?

Tags: support, faq

The current COVID-19 crisis impacts academia in several ways: teaching and exams are moved online, conferences are cancelled, travel is restricted, etc.
If you are here because of this, here is a brief introduction to our site and resources that may help you.

#### Finding existing questions

We have the tag [covid-19](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covid-19) for questions specific about the Corona crisis, but older questions about [online-learning](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-learning) and similar may apply here as well. We maintain collections of questions and external resources sorted by topic:

- [remote teaching, learning, and exams](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4681)
- [conferences](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4682)
- [other](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4683)

#### New questions

If you have a question that is not covered by this, please [ask it](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/).
Please ensure that your question is focused and clearly states which information you need.
Be aware that the following questions are not suited for our site:

- Scientific questions on immunology and epidemiology can be asked on [Medical Sciences](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/) or [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).
- General travelling questions can be asked on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) or [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).
- [Math Educators SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) and [Computer-Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) may help you with questions that are specific to teaching in those fields or that are about teaching outside of academia (e.g., at high schools).
- Questions on the regulations of individual institutions can only be answered by those institutions and may be quickly outdated in light of the crisis. Please see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406) for more information.
- Questions whose answers will be mostly based on speculation about upcoming political and administrative decisions and the further development of the crisis [are not suited for this site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) (and you won’t get good answers anywhere).

#### Chatroom

We also have a [chatroom for online learning](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105448/online-learning-chat) and [our general chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/the-ivory-tower) where you may find informal help.
However, to talk there, [you need 20 reputation on the site first](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).

#### Contribute

If you can, **please contribute**, in particular by curating the lists of relevant questions.
If you find any question that should be referenced here but isn’t, please add it.
You can also link relevant resources on other Stack Exchange sites or the Internet in general, but please mark them by stating where they point.

If you can provide better or complementary answers to some of the relevant questions, this is also very welcome.

You can propose other things we can do as a community [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4673/7734).

Comment: Is it worth posting this to meta.SE as well??

Comment: @ScottSeidman: I don’t think it will get much visibility there, in particular not by those who need it. Of course, it may also be useful to have similar collections on other sites like [travel.se], [health.se], …

Comment: Thanks for doing this. Lots of effort. Appreciated.

Comment: Thank you so much! Next time my colleagues are complaining about our students getting too much help on math.SE, I will point out that when you really need fast answers, the SE sites are where to go.

Answer (score 31):

## Remote teaching, studying, and exams

#### General and Other

- [Tips for transition to online classrooms given university shutdowns in response to COVID-19](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145370)
- [How to get students to use the course forum?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/83224)
- [What makes an online course a valuable learning experience for a student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/49881)
- [How much work is preparing a MOOC-ish course](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/54275)
- [How should faculty implement STEM classes that require hands-on lab experience in online learning platforms given COVID-19 pandemic?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145732)
- [How shall we teach math online?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18031/75) (Math Educators SE)
- [Tools for running classes remotely](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/6236/25) (Computer-Science Educators SE)
- [Please do a bad job of putting your courses online](https://anygoodthing.com/2020/03/12/please-do-a-bad-job-of-putting-your-courses-online/) (blog post about time investment and differences between emergency online teaching and regular one; somewhat US-specific)
- [Advice to those about to teach online because of the corona-virus](https://www.tonybates.ca/2020/03/09/advice-to-those-about-to-teach-online-because-of-the-corona-virus/) (Tony Bates)
- [Online Teaching with the most basic of tools – email](https://homonym.ca/published/online-teaching-with-the-most-basic-of-tools-email/) (Homonym)
- [So You Want to Temporarily Teach Online](https://www.insidehighered.com/advice/2020/03/11/practical-advice-instructors-faced-abrupt-move-online-teaching-opinion) (Inside Higher Ed)
- [What Teachers in China Have Learned in the Past Month](https://www.edutopia.org/article/what-teachers-china-have-learned-past-month) (Edutopia)

#### Other Collections (all external)

- [Educause](https://library.educause.edu/topics/information-technology-management-and-leadership/covid19)
- [Distance Design Education](https://distancedesigneducation.wordpress.com/) (blog dedicated to the eponymous topic, but with broader applicability)

#### Exams, Exercises, and other Evaluation

- [What methods can be used in online exams to genuinely test the students' knowledge and capabilities?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145494)
- [How to detect cheating when students take online quizzes or exams from home?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145102)
- [Can online recording of work area at home be made a mandatory criterion for passing exams midway through a course?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/147884)
- [Creating a secure test environment for a programming lab practical](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145321)
- [YouTube video assignments?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145362)
- [Online tool for receiving student files](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16250)
- [How is a Coursera exam typically conducted?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3611)
- [Are online exam proctoring services efficient and trustworthy?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/114001)
- [Should a professor give students a take-home exam when the answers might be available online?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/79083)
- [Other students can easily cheat on a test and the grading system is relative – should I cheat and what else can I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/147978)
- [How to prevent cheating on take-home exams](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38073)
- [Fellow student asked question from take-home exam on Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/102064)
- [How to design online tests and prevent cheating?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/6231/25) (Computer-Science Educators SE)
- [What evaluation methods can be used that don't involve testing but are adaptable to online courses](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/6234/25) (Computer-Science Educators SE)

#### Lectures and interactions

- [Alternatives to big-name proprietary remote-lecturing tools](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145280)
- [Software to live-stream presentations](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145222)
- [How do you record your lectures?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10214)
- [How to create PDF of slides with audio?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2862)
- [Etiquette or useful guidelines while making video lectures](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/13875)
- [How important is seeing the face of the instructor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61282)
- [Is there any system that enables online office hours?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/42639)
- [How much effort does it take to record video courses?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/9221)
- [Using Discord to support online teaching](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145389)
- [My professor is not teaching his online course himself, but uses publicly available videos instead. Is this appropriate?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145820)
- [Online Whiteboard Application with Simple Latex Support](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18030/75) (Math Educators SE)

#### Course Design and Material

- [Online vs hard copy, which texts are students more likely to read?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/107721)
- [Are there any legal issues in having someone's book as the basis and as a textbook for an online course?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14257)
- [Digital media rights for online courses (US)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56906)
- [Can you describe a required online science course that used discussion well?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19944)
- [How to read a textbook for distance learning coursework - do I need to work on fact recall, or is understanding enough?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7514)

#### Humour

- [Michael Bruening
  – I will survive (teaching online)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCe5PaeAeew) (YouTube)

Comment: Useful tips [here too](https://www.ctl.upenn.edu/resources-and-strategies-teaching-remotely)

Comment: And also [here](https://www.panopto.com/blog/prolonged-campus-shutdowns-spark-a-surge-in-remote-learning/).

Comment: @luchonacho: Thinking about it, I see no reason why we should not also collect external resources. Feel free to edit them into the answer.

Comment: @luchonacho: On a second thought, I would not include those links. The first is very specific to that university’s systems; the second one is paywalled.

Answer (score 15):

## Other questions and resources pertaining to the COVID-19 crisis

#### Publications

- [In this time of crisis, would the journals Nature and Science prioritize papers about COVID-19?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145243)
- [Has the rate of papers uploaded to arXiv changed due to Covid-19?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145583)
- [How does the COVID-19 crisis affect durations of peer review and editorial handling?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145539)
- [Acknowledging local government for quarantine measures](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145638)

#### Remote collaborations, job interviews, etc.

- [What are useful tips and tricks for collaborating remotely?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2071)
- [How could one prepare for a telecon interview for a government lab?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/36886)
- [Advice/guidance when interviewing for a faculty or postdoc job via Skype or phone?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/1137)
- [What kind of video conference software do academics use?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/43940)
- [How to present a paper via skype?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/64873)
- [Evaluation criteria for 3-minute teaching demonstration over Skype?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/101890)
- [Coronavirus, school lockdown and future uncertainty](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145238)
- [Asking for status of faculty position search during coronavirus pandemic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145516)
- [How can I best adapt my seminar slides for a virtual presentation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145877)
- [A few simple tips for better online meetings (COVID-19 edition)](https://www.media.mit.edu/posts/a-few-simple-tips-for-better-online-meetings-covid-19-edition/) (MIT Media Lab)

#### Employment and Applications

- [Postdoc position "on hold" due to covid-19](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145653)
- [academic job offers during Coronavirus](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145566)
- [Who might lose a job in academia due to covid19?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145962)
- [Can I still ask my prospective advisor (guide) for a confirmation letter in the middle of Covid-19](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145807)
- [Can PhD programs rescind their PhD offers from this cycle due to COVID-19?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145677)

#### Working from home or without direct contact

- [Working from home tips from our experienced remote employees](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/12/working-from-home-tips-from-our-experienced-remote-employees) (Stack Overflow Blog)

Answer (score 12):

## Conferences

- [How to deal with the COVID-19 outbreak while organizing a conference?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145068)
- [Can I put an invited talk on my CV if the conference was canceled?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145328)