# Can I ask about the research level of a certain university here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness, asking-questions

For some reasons I need to know about the level of research conducted in a certain university (**not because I want to study there**: I got my Ph.D. years ago). Specifically, I'm interested in a certain department. I did some due diligence, such as looking at the Google Scholar profile of one of the professors, and looking at the website, but I didn't get a conclusive answer. Can I ask this question on Academia.SE?

Answer (score 3):

The question you propose would be a [shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/7734) as it asks us to evaluate an individual university.
What you can ask about is *how* to evaluate the research level of an anonymous university (unless we already have a question on that).

Comment: Interesting. I will check if a similar question exists, otherwise ask it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what "level of research" implies, but I imagine that would not be a good question for this site, as that's fairly subjective. I can't imagine what we'd post beyond what you already were able to find for yourself.

Comment: Quality of research...how would you call it otherwise? To make an example, I expect universities in the Ivy League to excel at research _in general_. _In particular_, the Department of Statistics at Columbia produces excellent research. The Stanford Center for Turbulence Research is known for the high level of its research in Computational Fluid Dynamics, and the Department of Computer Science is one of the leading groups on Computer Vision/Deep Learning (yeah, I know Stanford is not part of IL). That's what I meant with "level of research".

Comment: Basically, I wanted to know if that university was at a similar level as Berkeley, Columbia, Stanford, etc. for what it concerns research (so I wasn't interested in teaching).