# My question disappeared and my rep went 100 points down without any information/notification given to me, even post deletion. Why?

Tags: discussion

I had recently asked a question about authenticity/information about a scientific research abstracts database called inexsy ([www.inexsy.com](http://www.inexsy.com)) (They call it information exchange system on their site). I had asked this question a few days back and just a couple of hours ago some new user ( I dont recall his username) posting irrelavant comments and answers and by the time I saw, he was rude to a user (Scaahu)(I dont know if he is a moderator). There was a close vote and a downvote that happened in between the exchange between these users. After a an hour or so I came back to this site to see my question disappear and a -100 to my reputation, all without any information/nortification from anyone. I just saw Rep go down and when I searched the question it was not there. I'd like to know what happened and why my rep was -100 and question deleted with no information given to me, even post deletion. I do not have the link to the question. Appreciate some information.

Answer (score 3):

The question was flagged as spam by two users. I reviewed the flags and agreed that it looked spammy, and deleted it as such. A post deleted as spam causes a penalty of 100 reputation points.

I apologize if I have misinterpreted your post but, probably, from the way it was formulated, it would have attracted other spam flags anyway. I'll ask the SE staff to clear the spam flag so that you can recovery the reputation, but please don't repost that question, even in a different form: it would be closed as a [shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Massimo. It clears the air. Otherwise I was wondering what would have happened.