# About saving one question for others access (google index and ...)

Tags: discussion

I think I have asked a good question which could be useful for others, and be in google index.

But the question has been recognized as [a shopping question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping), as you can see below:

[Finding a classmate to achieve access to academic learning process and connection for non-registered learning enthusiasts [closed]](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175467/finding-a-classmate-to-achieve-access-to-academic-learning-process-and-connectio/175528?noredirect=1#175528)

So if possible I like to know which part of my question must be deleted to become open and its information could be used for others via Google search or direct access?

**Update 1:**

so I am trying to add more details and will answer to the below question:

> 1. What is your plan for after the program finishes? Will you apply to
>    the program again? Will you try to get jobs by claiming that you've
>    done all this self-study?
> 2. Why do you need to follow along with a particular course at all? Why
>    not just buy some textbooks?
> 3. If you succeed in connecting with a student who got admitted to a
>    university in your field, what do you want them to do for you?

So :

1- I am working as a freelancer and studied the M.Sc. at Biomedical engineer which like continuing my academic education with is related to my job field, so I will apply for University entrance exam in the Cognitive science with my new trained wights (or will apply for another academic field exam. The reason for this action is online academic opportunity and my eagerness to be updated and connected with university and its connection (teachers, students, facilities like labs and ...).

2- As I described, the connections and facilities of university and being in an academic environment is important for me (One of our masters had said every 4 year engineering science fundamentally would change, and I have seen this in my 10 years
Absenting and not being in academic programs).

3- In this connection I Hope to have access to :

- accessing to public and predefined program contents, like course
  syllabus, references, power points.
- Also, if they don't have copyright problem or ... accessing to class
  video recorded, but we could cover the course information on  the internet
  source from  online course equivalents like said at [the question
  answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/175467/finding-a-classmate-to-achieve-access-to-academic-learning-process-and-connectio/175528?noredirect=1#comment471212_175528) (Coursera, EDx, or ...).
- And be in connection with them for team working on their exams and
  course experiment by our more desired field of study and courses,
  this features give us more access to the teachers and academic
  facilities and help us to newer connection and networks.
- Also, if possible, I like to have some connection with them for
  reviewing the course or asking about the misunderstanding  parts
  of courses by creating some online group like skype for some meeting
  at the end of weekends.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the "it could be useful for others" part is a red herring. A recipe for tiramisu is also useful content, but this site is not the best place for it. "How can I modify my question to make it on-topic here" is a reasonable question, but do not start from the assumption that your question has a right to appear on academia.se just because it is useful. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the good news: I don't think your question is a shopping question. If you had asked for a specific forum where you could "advertise" for a partner, then your question would be a shopping question. But you are asking for more general advice.

Now for the more difficult part: your post is quite confusing. I considered trying to help you by editing it, but I just kept getting more confused.

So: some questions. Don't reply to me; instead, edit the answers into your post. I (or anyone else) may suggest some additional edits, and then we'll see where we are.

- What is your plan for after the program finishes? Will you apply to the program again? Will you try to get jobs by claiming that you've done all this self-study?
- Why do you need to follow along with a particular course at all? Why not just buy some textbooks?
- If you succeed in connecting with a student who got admitted to a university in your field, what do you want them to do for you?

Comment: Not having seen any follow-up, I have updated the close reason to "unclear what you are asking." I think we can consider this matter closed (as it were).

Comment: Thanks, @cag51, I have updated the question and as I guess the SE don't send any notification I have written this comment.