# Deciphering time

Tags: discussion

In August 24, 2022 I asked a question on the main site, https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/188081/8575, that was summarized as

> Do you know of other scientific journals (in any field) that "forbid"
> (discourage) judgement on importance/significance/impact to be used as
> criterion in the recommendation/decision process for publication?

It was closed because

1. << We don't allow questions asking for individual or lists of journals, schools, etc.>> –
   Bryan Krause
2. I was also directed to the post about "shopping questions", https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3658/8575. that <<explains the reasons we don't want to have these sorts of questions.>>

OK. **Can then somebody please explain why the question [What opportunities are there to write casual articles in math?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/208347/8575), was not summarily closed,**
even though it explicitly ends by asking

> **Are there any prominent mathematics magazines whose target audience is
> on the younger side (e.g. 16–25)?**

Answer (score 3):

> Can then somebody please explain why the question...was not summarily closed...

Because no one flagged it? Mods don't really summarily review questions; rather, we respond to flags or sometimes we stumble across things ourselves. This is the SE model; the pro is that it's community driven, the con is that it's sometimes uneven.

> even though it explicitly ends by asking...

The last sentence might arguably be a shopping question, but the title question seems answerable to me. While we can't (shouldn't) recommend specific venues, there may be a general answer that about how to publish results that are more formal than a blog but more accessible than an actual paper. So I personally wouldn't hammer this one, would leave it up to the community.

Comment: I wish to add that the asker has the privilege to cast close votes.